# networkx: how to uncover arrowheads from nodes with bigger size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-visualization

I am plotting a graph using networkx. The default `node_size=500; width=1.0` is too small for me, so I need to enlarge the graph. For example:

```py
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3)])
pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=1000, alpha=0.3)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=2.)
plt.show()
```

However, in the resulting plot, the location of the edges' arrow head and tail are not adjusted accordingly, and thus are covered under nodes with bigger size (I used transparency to show this). See below:

[image]

If I directly use `nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=1000, width=2.)` then the result is good:

[image]

However, I could not simply use this method, since I have different colors and sizes for different nodes and edges.

Do you have any suggestions to uncover the arrowheads, or other methods to enlarge the graph for my case?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I just found it.. Also need to set `node_size` when plotting edges:

`nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=2., node_size=1000)`